# Spring-security.xml code based configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm looking for an example of how to do a code based configuration of the spring-security.xml file. This is a standard spring-security.xml file that I'm using to guide myself.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

And this is a code based configuration class that I'm also using to guide myself

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")  // #1
          .password("password")
          .roles("USER")
          .and()
        .withUser("admin") // #2
          .password("password")
          .roles("ADMIN","USER");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
         .antMatchers("/resources/**"); // #3
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeUrls()
        .antMatchers("/signup","/about").permitAll() // #4
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // #6
        .anyRequest().authenticated() // 7
        .and()
    .formLogin()  // #8
        .loginUrl("/login") // #9
        .permitAll(); // #5
  }
}
```

But if you see in the spring-security.xml file there are these URLS

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
```

How do I put those URL in code? or should I just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

These URLs are where you find spring security XML schemas and the URL ended in `.xsd` are the XML schemas itself.

Did you try access http://www.springframework.org/schema/security? If so, you will see some XSD files, which are XML schemas.

[From XML schema recommendation/specification](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema):

> XML Schemas express shared vocabularies and allow machines to carry
>   out rules made by people. They provide a means for defining the
>   structure, content and semantics of XML documents in more detail.

[An XML schema describes the structure of an XML document](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/). In other works, XML schemas will help and guarantee to you that your XML config is a valid XML.

As you are now using code based configuration, you can just ignore, is not necessary, the *schema* is now the Java code, interfaces, methods, etc.